# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined OOP

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
    private function sendVerification($username, $email)
    {
        global $pdo;

        $this->check = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where user_name = :username AND user_email = :email");
        $this->check->execute(array(
        ":username" => $username,
        ":email" => $email
        ));

        if ($this->check->rowCount())
        {
            $this->get = $this->check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $this->insert = $pdo->prepare
            ("
            INSERT INTO account_verification 
            (user_id, generated_code, date, time) 
            VALUES
            (:id, :code, CUTDATE(), CURTIME())
            ");

            $this->insert->execute(array(
            ":id" => $this->get['user_id'],
            "generated_code" => Users::generateCode($email)
            ));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new exception ("An error has occured!");
        }
    }
```

Accessing this ***static***:

```
    public static function generateCode($salt)
    {
        return substr(hash('sha512', $salt), 0, 15);
    }
```

First I am using the username & email to validate that there's a row with them,
Then I am adding a var that will hold a fetched array of it.

*And then I am checking if its rowCount, and then inserting data.*

**Problem:**

**I am getting this error**

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

I am not too sure why I am getting this, I've never experienced this error, I've read about it but didn't understand what would be the problem in my code.

**Question:**

*Pretty much, why does that error mean, and what is causing this?*

Comment: Your parameter is `:code`, not `:generated_code` as you have in the `execute()` array.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your insert query you reference a maned parameter of `:code`, while when you execute the prepared statement, you use an improper parameter reference of  `generated_code` (with no colon at all).  Change that parameter reference to `:code` and it should work.

The error message means pretty much exactly what it says, that the parameter `generated_code` was not defined.